# How to pass the remote notifications I have for Iphone to Watch OS?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch, remote-notifications

I'm developing a very huge App, that already has Remote Push Notifications. This notifications also includes the Facebook ones, and they're showing very well at the iPhone and iPad, the thing is that now I need to show the same notifications at the Apple Watch, and I have no idea how can I do that.

This is my AppDelegate, where I declare de remote notifications:

```
  func handleNotification(_ application: UIApplication,userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        if let notification = userInfo["notification"] as?  NSDictionary {

            let notiicationInfo = notification
            let notiicationAPS = userInfo["aps"] as! NSDictionary
            let type = notiicationInfo["type"] as! String!
            let name = notiicationInfo["name"] as! String!
            let value = notiicationInfo["value"] as! String!
            let message = notiicationAPS["alert"] as! String!
            NSLog("notiicationInfo  \(notiicationInfo)")

            var promotions :  [[String:Any]]? = []

            promotions!.append(["id": name as AnyObject, "name":message as AnyObject, "creative":"" as AnyObject, "position":"1" as AnyObject])

            if let customBar = self.window!.rootViewController as? CustomBarViewController {
                if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background ||  application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive)
                {
                    let dataLayer: TAGDataLayer = TAGManager.instance().dataLayer
                    dataLayer.push(["ecommerce": ""])
                    dataLayer.push(["ecommerce": NSNull()])
                    dataLayer.push(["event": "promotionClick", "ecommerce": [ "promoClick" : ["promotions": promotions!] ] ] )

                    let delay = 2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                    let time = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time, execute: {
                        customBar.handleNotification(type!,name:name!,value:value!)
                    })
                }

                else {
                    let dataLayer: TAGDataLayer = TAGManager.instance().dataLayer
                    dataLayer.push(["ecommerce": ""])
                    dataLayer.push(["ecommerce": NSNull()])
                    dataLayer.push(["ecommerce": ["promoView":["promotions": promotions!] ],"event":"ecommerce"  ])

                    _ = AlertController.presentViewController(message!,
                        icon:UIImage(named:"alerta_hello.png"),
                        titleButton: NSLocalizedString("general.continue",comment:""),
                        action: {() in

                            let dataLayer: TAGDataLayer = TAGManager.instance().dataLayer
                            dataLayer.push(["ecommerce": ""])
                            dataLayer.push(["ecommerce": NSNull()])
                            dataLayer.push(["event": "promotionClick", "ecommerce": [ "promoClick" : ["promotions": promotions!] ] ] )

                            if let controller = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
                                if controller.presentedViewController != nil {
                                    if let tutController =  controller.presentedViewController as?  ImageDisplayCollectionViewController {
                                        tutController.closeModal()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            customBar.handleNotification(type!,name:name!,value:value!)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
            UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
        }

    }
```

Does anyone knows what do I have to add to my code for showing this notifications on an Apple Watch? I already have added the Watch Os Target, but I don't know where to declare this remote notifications on that device.

Comment: Have you actually tested if the notifications are being displayed? Take a look to the [notification essentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1), thats supposed to happen automatically.

Comment: The notifications are being displayed on the Iphone and Ipad, the issue is not with the notifications, the thing is that I don't know how to display them on an Apple Watch device.

Comment: Ok but are you sure that they are not being displayed in the watch? Remember push notifications only work on physical devices, not simulators.

Comment: You cannot route notifications to the Apple Watch specifically,  iOS displays notifications on the watch if the user has permitted that app to do so and iOS considers that the user is not actively using the phone (e.g. it is locked). In your watch extension you can add code to handle the formatting of notifications when they are delivered to the watch

Comment: Ok, that was the issue, that I've tried to see the notifications at the watch simulator, so now I'm gonna try it on a physical device, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple Watch Notification Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1):

> Apple Watch displays notifications at appropriate times. When one of
>   your app’s local or remote notification arrives on the user’s iPhone,
>   iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on
>   Apple Watch.

So, you don't need to add extra code in order to get your notifications displayed on the Apple Watch (If you would like to implement some custom notification action, thats another [story](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/08/interactive-notifications-for-ios-and-apple-watch/)). Remember push notifications can only be tested on physical devices by default, as you commented, that was the reason why you couldn't receive the notifications in the simulator.

Heres a [library to test remote notifications on iOS Simulator](https://github.com/acoomans/SimulatorRemoteNotifications) (I couldn't find if someone have tested this with the Apple Watch Simulator, you will have to give it a try).